# How do i make a song pause and play with the same button(while the button changes)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that changes from a full speaker icon to an empty speaker icon when i click on it. I have a song which pauses and plays when i click the button. My problem is that when you spam the button sometimes the icon will change too fast and the song won't pause so that leaves the song playing while it has the empty speaker icon. How do i get it so they are connected and if its paused the icon will be the right one?

This is the song

```
<source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>


<script type="text/javascript">
```

This is the Icon

```
 <div class="col">
 <button class="btn float-right purple" onclick="fav()" ><i  
 id="pauseplay" class="fas fa-volume-up whiteicon fa-lg"></i></button>
 </div>
```

This is the JS that connects to the icon and pauses and plays the song

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



 (function(){
 var playing = !!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('ontouchstart' in 
  document.documentElement) || !!window.ontouchstart || (!!window.Touch 
 && !!window.Touch.length) || !!window.onmsgesturechange || 
 (window.DocumentTouch && window.document instanceof 
 window.DocumentTouch),
 snd = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0],
 ctrl = document.getElementById('pauseplay');
 playing = !playing;
 ctrl.title = playing? 'Pause' : 'Play';
    if(playing){snd.autoplay = false; ctrl.src = '**your website url** 
 here/images/pause.png';}
    ctrl.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(playing){
        snd.pause();


    } else {
        snd.play();

    }
    playing = !playing;
    ctrl.title = playing? 'Pause' : 'Play';

    }, false);
  })();
 </script>
```

This is the JS that changes the icon

```
  <script>
  function fav() {
  var icon = document.getElementById("pauseplay");
  if (icon.classList.contains("fa-volume-up")) {
  icon.classList.remove("fa-volume-up");
  icon.classList.add("fa-volume-mute");
  song.play();
  } else {
  icon.classList.remove("fa-volume-mute");
  icon.classList.add("fa-volume-up");
    song.pause();
  }
  }


 </script>
```

Comment: Instead of checking the `classList` you should really be checking if the `<audio>` element is paused or not.

Comment: Why do you have two separate functions? Just change the class as well inside the other function.